# Cannot pass data from JSONResult back to handler using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to have the following workflow:

1. Ajax call to page model handler to trigger database and creation of some viewmodels and return the result as `JSONResult`
2. Pass back the result of step 1 to another handler in order to reload a partial view

Between step 1 and 2 there is some data handling using JS. But this is out of scope, since the data is only read and not changed.

Step 1 is working fine. But step 2 does not. Here is a short code example:

Step 1:
Ajax:

```
            var searchArea = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtSearchArea').value);
            var latitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hiddenLat').value);
            var longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hiddenLong').value);

            var requestData = JSON.stringify({'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude, 'searchArea': searchArea});

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Request.Scheme://@Request.Host@Request.Path?handler=GetCompaniesWithinSearchArea',
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: requestData
            }).fail(function (x) {
                alert('Error fetching companies in search area.');
            }).done(function (result) {
                reloadSearchResultPartialView(result);
            });
```

C#:

```
        public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostGetCompaniesWithinSearchAreaAsync([FromBody] LatitudeLongitudeSearchArea latitudeLongitudeSearchArea)
        {
            var latitude = latitudeLongitudeSearchArea.Latitude;
            var longitude = latitudeLongitudeSearchArea.Longitude;
            var searchArea = latitudeLongitudeSearchArea.SearchArea;

            var idsOfcompaniesInArea = await _companiesService.GetIdsOfCompaniesWithinSearchAreaAsync(latitude, longitude, searchArea));

            var companyInSearchAreaVMs = await _companiesInSearchAreaViewModelFactory.Create(idsOfcompaniesInArea);

            return new JsonResult(companyInSearchAreaVMs);
        }
```

with `_companiesInSearchAreaViewModelFactory.Create` returning `List<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel>`.

Step 2:
Normally I use the javascript `load(...)` method to invoke reloading of a partial view.
So I was trying to use this approach again.

JS:

```
function reloadSearchResultPartialView(searchResult) {
$('#divSearchResult').load('@Request.Scheme://@Request.Host@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList&companyInSearchAreaViewModels=' + searchResult);
}
```

where searchResult is the response result of step 1. Data have not been changed between step 1 and 2.

C# - this is the handler for reloading the partial view.

```
        public PartialViewResult OnGetReloadCompaniesInAreaList(List<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel> companyInSearchAreaViewModels)
        {
            var result = new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_CompaniesInAreaList",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IList<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel>>(ViewData, companyInSearchAreaViewModels)
            };

            return result;
        }
```

The handler for reloading the partial view is called, but the list of viewmodels is always an empty list.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
function reloadSearchResultPartialView(searchResult) {
   $('#divSearchResult').load('@Request.Scheme://@Request.Host@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList&companyInSearchAreaViewModels=' + searchResult);
}
```

to

```
function reloadSearchResultPartialView(searchResult) {
     var arrStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(searchResult));
     $('#divSearchResult').load('@Request.Scheme://@Request.Host@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList&companyInSearchAreaViewModels='+arrStr);
 }
```

And in PageModel

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetReloadCompaniesInAreaList(List<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel> companyInSearchAreaViewModels)
        {
            var result = new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_CompaniesInAreaList",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IList<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel>>(ViewData, companyInSearchAreaViewModels)
            };

            return result;
        }
```

to

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetReloadCompaniesInAreaList(string companyInSearchAreaViewModels)
{
            List<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel>>(companyInSearchAreaViewModels);

            var result = new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_CompaniesInAreaList",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IList<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel>>(ViewData, data)
            };

            return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why it happens

> but the list of viewmodels is always an empty list.

That's because your server expects a querystring like this:

```
handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList
&[0].prop1= 11
&[0].prop2=12
...
&[1].prop1=21
&[1].prop2=22
...
```

However, by using

```
$('#divSearchResult').load('@Request.Scheme://@Request.Host@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList&companyInSearchAreaViewModels=' + searchResult);
```

You're sending the querystring like:

```
handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList&companyInSearchAreaViewModels=[object
```

### How to Fix

There're several ways to fix that problem.

1. The easiest way is to change the json array to a form-urlencoded string, for example, change your `reloadSearchResultPartialView()`function as below:

   ```js
   function reloadSearchResultPartialView(searchResult) {
       //$('#divSearchResult').load('@Request.Scheme://@Request.Host@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList&companyInSearchAreaViewModels=' + searchResult);
       $('#divSearchResult').load('@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList', $.param(createFormUrlEncodedPayload("",searchResult)));
   }
   // my helper function that recursively convert a plain js obj to a form-urlencoded string
   function createFormUrlEncodedPayload(name,o){
       var payload = {};
       function _objectNotNull(value){ return value !== null && typeof value === "object"; }
       function _create(prefix,obj) {
           for(var prop in obj) {
               if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                   var key =prefix?
                       (isNaN(prop)? key = prefix + "." + prop : key = prefix + ".[" + prop + "]") :
                       (isNaN(prop)? key = prop : key = "[" + prop + "]");
                   var value = obj[prop];
                   if(_objectNotNull(value)) 
                       _create(key, value); 
                   else 
                       payload[key]=value;
               }
           }
       };
       _create(name,o);
       return payload;
   }
   ```
2. Or as an alternative, you can make your server to receive **HTTP POST** request instead `GET`,

   ```
   public PartialViewResult OnPostReloadCompaniesInAreaList([FormBody]List<CompanyInSearchAreaViewModel> companyInSearchAreaViewModels)
   {
       ...            
   }
   ```

   and then replace the `$.load()` to :

   ```
   $.ajax({
      url: '@Request.Path?handler=ReloadCompaniesInAreaList',
      method:'POST',
      contentType:"application/json",
      data: searchResult,
      success: function(resp){
         $('#divSearchResult').html(resp)
      },
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your useful explanations. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. Therefore I have chosen the answer of @SerhatDev as correct.